# packing and unpacking variable length array/string using the struct module in python

Tags: python, binary, struct, python-3.x

I am trying to get a grip around the packing and unpacking of binary data in Python 3. Its actually not that hard to understand, except one problem:

what if I have a variable length textstring and want to pack and unpack this in the most elegant manner?

As far as I can tell from the manual I can only unpack fixed size strings directly? In that case, are there any elegant way of getting around this limitation without padding lots and lots of unnecessary zeroes?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `struct` module does only support fixed-length structures.  For variable-length strings, your options are either:

- Dynamically construct your format string (a `str` will have to be converted to a `bytes` before passing it to `pack()`):

  ```
  s = bytes(s, 'utf-8')    # Or other appropriate encoding
  struct.pack("I%ds" % (len(s),), len(s), s)
  ```
- Skip `struct` and just use normal string methods to add the string to your `pack()`-ed output: `struct.pack("I", len(s)) + s`

For unpacking, you just have to unpack a bit at a time:

```
(i,), data = struct.unpack("I", data[:4]), data[4:]
s, data = data[:i], data[i:]
```

If you're doing a lot of this, you can always add a helper function which uses `calcsize` to do the string slicing:

```
def unpack_helper(fmt, data):
    size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    return struct.unpack(fmt, data[:size]), data[size:]
```

Comment: if adding the length/charcount to the binary data, how would you unpack it?

Comment: The OP's question mentions Python 3 specifically, and this answer doesn't work in Python 3 because string objects no longer support the buffer interface.

Comment: @jonesy: The only part that didn't work was the first snippet, passing a `str` to `pack()`; this has now been addressed.

Comment: For unpacking of C styled string in binary data block works also something like this `s.rstrip(b'\x00').decode("utf_8")`.

Comment: Slicing is much slower than using unpack_from with an optional offset, and there is no need to calculate the size.

Answer (score 10):

I've googled up this question and a couple of solutions.

## [construct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/construct)

An elaborate, flexible solution.

> Instead of writing imperative code to parse a piece of data, you declaratively define a data structure that describes your data. As this data structure is not code, you can use it in one direction to parse data into Pythonic objects, and in the other direction, convert (“build”) objects into binary data.
>
> The library provides both simple, atomic constructs (such as integers of various sizes), as well as composite ones which allow you form hierarchical structures of increasing complexity. Construct features bit and byte granularity, easy debugging and testing, an easy-to-extend subclass system, and lots of primitive constructs to make your work easier:

**Updated**: Python 3.x, construct 2.10.67; also they have native PascalString, so renamed

```py
    from construct import *
    
    myPascalString = Struct(
        "length" / Int8ul,
        "data" / Bytes(lambda ctx: ctx.length)
    )

    >>> myPascalString.parse(b'\x05helloXXX')
    Container(length=5, data=b'hello')
    >>> myPascalString.build(Container(length=6, data=b"foobar"))
    b'\x06foobar'


    myPascalString2 = ExprAdapter(myPascalString,
        encoder=lambda obj, ctx: Container(length=len(obj), data=obj),
        decoder=lambda obj, ctx: obj.data
    )

    >>> myPascalString2.parse(b"\x05hello")
    b'hello'

    >>> myPascalString2.build(b"i'm a long string")
    b"\x11i'm a long string"
```

***ed**: Also pay attention to that ExprAdapter, once native PascalString won't be doing what you need from it, this is what you will be doing.*

## [netstruct](https://github.com/stendec/netstruct)

A quick solution if you only need a `struct` extension for variable length byte sequences. Nesting a variable-length structure can be achieved by `pack`ing the first `pack` results.

> NetStruct supports a new formatting character, the dollar sign ($). The dollar sign represents a variable-length string, encoded with its length preceeding the string itself.

**edit**: Looks like the length of a variable-length string uses the same data type as the elements. Thus, the maximum length of variable-length string of bytes is 255, if words - 65535, and so on.

```
import netstruct
>>> netstruct.pack(b"b$", b"Hello World!")
b'\x0cHello World!'

>>> netstruct.unpack(b"b$", b"\x0cHello World!")
[b'Hello World!']
```

Comment: You wrote about `netstruct`: "looks like it only uses one byte for a string length". However, the format character before the `$` sign indicates the format to be used for its length. You chose `b`, which is a 1-byte integer. If you had chosen `h`, `netstruct` would have used a 2-byte integer to represent the length.

Comment: good answer, Alpha and Omega of my learning curve with construct, started from this answer and after fiddling a day got back for ExprAdapter as a solution for my: *almost works as I need it*. I wish my answers be that helpful.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way that I was able to do a variable length when packing a string is:

```
pack('{}s'.format(len(string)), string)
```

when unpacking it is kind of the same way

```
unpack('{}s'.format(len(data)), data)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's some wrapper functions I wrote which help, they seem to work.

Here's the unpacking helper:

```
def unpack_from(fmt, data, offset = 0):
    (byte_order, fmt, args) = (fmt[0], fmt[1:], ()) if fmt and fmt[0] in ('@', '=', '<', '>', '!') else ('@', fmt, ())
    fmt = filter(None, re.sub("p", "\tp\t",  fmt).split('\t'))
    for sub_fmt in fmt:
        if sub_fmt == 'p':
            (str_len,) = struct.unpack_from('B', data, offset)
            sub_fmt = str(str_len + 1) + 'p'
            sub_size = str_len + 1
        else:
            sub_fmt = byte_order + sub_fmt
            sub_size = struct.calcsize(sub_fmt)
        args += struct.unpack_from(sub_fmt, data, offset)
        offset += sub_size
    return args
```

Here's the packing helper:

```
def pack(fmt, *args):
    (byte_order, fmt, data) = (fmt[0], fmt[1:], '') if fmt and fmt[0] in ('@', '=', '<', '>', '!') else ('@', fmt, '')
    fmt = filter(None, re.sub("p", "\tp\t",  fmt).split('\t'))
    for sub_fmt in fmt:
        if sub_fmt == 'p':
            (sub_args, args) = ((args[0],), args[1:]) if len(args) > 1 else ((args[0],), [])
            sub_fmt = str(len(sub_args[0]) + 1) + 'p'
        else:
            (sub_args, args) = (args[:len(sub_fmt)], args[len(sub_fmt):])
            sub_fmt = byte_order + sub_fmt
        data += struct.pack(sub_fmt, *sub_args)
    return data
```

Answer (score 4):

To pack use

```
packed=bytes('sample string','utf-8')
```

To unpack use

```
string=str(packed)[2:][:-1]
```

This works only on utf-8 string and quite simple workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Another silly but very simple approach: (PS:as others mentioned there is no pure pack/unpack support for that, with that in mind)

```
import struct


def pack_variable_length_string(s: str) -> bytes:
    str_size_bytes = struct.pack('!Q', len(s))
    str_bytes = s.encode('UTF-8')
    return str_size_bytes + str_bytes


def unpack_variable_length_string(sb: bytes, offset=0) -> (str, int):
    str_size_bytes = struct.unpack('!Q', sb[offset:offset + 8])[0]
    return sb[offset + 8:offset + 8 + str_size_bytes].decode('UTF-8'), 8 + str_size_bytes + offset


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = pack_variable_length_string('Worked maybe?') + \
        pack_variable_length_string('It seems it did?') + \
        pack_variable_length_string('Are you sure?') + \
        pack_variable_length_string('Surely.')
    next_offset = 0
    for i in range(4):
        s, next_offset = unpack_variable_length_string(b, next_offset)
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, but can't handle numeric number of fields, such as '6B' for 'BBBBBB'. The solution would be to expand format string in both functions before use. I came up with this:

```
def pack(fmt, *args):
  fmt = re.sub('(\d+)([^\ds])', lambda x: x.group(2) * int(x.group(1)), fmt)
  ...
```

And same for unpack. Maybe not most elegant, but it works :)