# Reading Strings from a binary file

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct, binaryfiles

I have a binary file written by the delphi. This is what i know:

- Block 1: 4 bytes,  stands for a integer value of 32 bits.
- Block 2: A String value (The length is not fixed for all binary files)
- Block 3: 4 bytes,  stands for a integer value of 32 bits.
- Block 4: A String value (The length is not fixed for all binary files)
- ...
- BlockN

i made this to read the first block value:

```
import struct

f = open("filename", 'rb')
value = struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))
```

---

What about the Strings values? What a good solution would be like? Is there any way to iterate over the string and find the final delimiter "\0" of each string value like in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that Delphi use a 7 bit integer compression to specify at beginning of a string, how many bytes need to read.I found [here](http://entitycrisis.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/7-bit-integer-compression-in-python.html) the same algorithm implemented with python. So, i just have to pass the file into `decode7bit(bytes):` function and it will tell me how many bytes i have to read forward.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex with the unpack if you don't know the length. I give you a reference which should solve your problem.
[packing and unpacking variable length array/string using the struct module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753589/packing-and-unpacking-variable-length-array-string-using-the-struct-module-in-py)