# How do I get my returned data to format through a structure?

Tags: python, qsys

I'm sending this to the server:

```
import requests 
response = requests.get('http://SERVER-IP/get.cgi?req=zones')
print(response.content)
```

I get back a string of data like this:

```
b'CS\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00MainAuditorium\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

On the website it lists a variable length structure

```c
typedef struct ZonesData {
    uint16_t            signature;              // Signature = 'CS'
    int16_t             version;                // Version = 0x0001 (or negative error code)
    uint8_t             reserved[2];            // -
    uint16_t            zoneCount;              // Number of zones
    ZoneRecord          zones[];                // Variable array of zone records
} ZonesData;

#define STACK_NAME_BUF_SIZE     16

typedef struct ZoneRecord {
    char                name[STACK_NAME_BUF_SIZE];  // Name of zone
    uint8_t             playbackIndex;          // Playback index
    uint8_t             joinGroup;              // Join group
    uint16_t            count;                  // Number of PresetID/Status pairs
    uint32_t            data[];                 // Array of PresetID/Status pairs (32 pairs max)
} ZoneRecord;
```

1. How can I get python to put the code in Human readable form?
2. Can a use the returned integers to say update a button on a UI?
   I'm assuming I can, I'm just not sure if I would reference to integer or the human readable of the integer.

Additonal project context: I am trying to get Qsys and Cueserver integrated so that Qsys touchpad buttons update when a new preset is fired from a Cueserver wall station.

Comment: have you tried `response.json`

Comment: @MZ It doesn't seem to be JSON so that would not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [packing and unpacking variable length array/string using the struct module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753589/packing-and-unpacking-variable-length-array-string-using-the-struct-module-in-py)

Answer (score 0):

My brother-in-law and I worked on it some this weekend he came up with this....
I am still working out exactly what he did so that i can modify it for additional responses. You can ask the server for a bunch of different strings back (all in the same raw format). Looks like I'll have to code an individual response for each one...

```
import requests
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

PresetStatusPair = namedtuple('PresetStatusPair', 'preset status')

class ZoneData:
def __init__(self, data, offset):
    self.size = 20

   self.name, self.playback_index, self.join_group, count = struct.unpack_from("16sBBH", data, offset)
    self.name = str(self.name, 'ascii')
    self.data = []
    for i in range(count):
        unpacked = struct.unpack_from("II", data, offset + self.size)
        self.data.append(PresetStatusPair._make(unpacked))
        self.size += 8


class ZonesData:
def __init__(self, data):
    if len(data) == 4:
        raise Exception("CS internal error")

    self.signature, self.version, zone_count_unused = struct.unpack_from("2sHxxH", data)
    self.signature = str(self.signature, 'ascii')
    self.parse_zone_records(data)

def parse_zone_records(self, data):
    self.zone_records = []
    offset = 8
    while offset < len(data):
        zone_data = ZoneData(data, offset)
        offset += zone_data.size
        self.zone_records.append(zone_data)


zones_data = ZonesData(data)
print(f"signature: {zones_data.signature}")
print(f"version  : {zones_data.version}")
print(f"records  :")

for record in zones_data.zone_records:
print(f"    name          : {record.name}")
print(f"    playback_index: {record.playback_index}")
print(f"    join_group    : {record.join_group}")
print(f"    data          : {record.data}")
```