# h264 reference frames

Tags: parsing, h.264, decoding

I'm looking for a algorithm of finding reference frames in h264 stream. The most common metod I saw  in different solutions was finding access unit delimiters and NAL of IDR type. Unfortunatelly most streams I checked didn't have NAL of IDR  type.
I'll be gratefull for help.
Regards 
Jacek

Comment: Still `IDR` NAL units should be there. How did you search?

Answer (score 8):

H264 frames split up by a special tag, called the startcode prefix, which is either of **0x00 0x00 0x01** OR **0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01**.  All the data between two startcodes comprises a NAL unit in H264 speak. So what you want to do is search for the startcode prefix in your h264 stream. The byte following the startcode prefix immediately is the **NAL header**. The lowest 5 bits of the NAL header will give you the NAL unit type. If nal_unit_type = 5, that particular NAL unit is a reference frame.

Something like this:

```
void h264_find_IDR_frame(char *buf)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if (buf[0]==0x00 && buf[1]==0x00 && buf[2]==0x01)
        {
            // Found a NAL unit with 3-byte startcode
            if(buf[3] & 0x1F == 0x5)
            {
                // Found a reference frame, do something with it
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (buf[0]==0x00 && buf[1]==0x00 && buf[2]==0x00 && buf[3]==0x01)
        {
            // Found a NAL unit with 4-byte startcode
            if(buf[4] & 0x1F == 0x5)
            {
                // Found a reference frame, do something with it
            }
            break;
        }
        buf++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the 3 byte start code is a the same as the 4 byte start code, but with just one less byte, you really don't need to handle both cases separately.  The first if will find both variants.

Comment: But if you only check for the first one and you have 4 byte start codes, you will be leaving a 0 before the start code, which could get some nal packets dirty.