# Basic examples with binary writing in python?

Tags: python, file, binary

I am beginner with python. ASCII files I can create, but with binary it seems more difficult to get in.
The writing of binary files got me confused, when I have not been able to find simplest code EXAMPLES, which would effectively reveal me, how it is actually done.

So, here I write things, which I would like to solve:

python: a=254, write value a to binary file.

file1: FE
file2: 00FE
file3: 000000FE
file4: FE00
file5: FE000000

python: string="00AABBCCDDEEFF"
file: 00AABBCCDDEEFF

python: string="999 This is ASCII"
file: 090909[and the rest same way converted]

So, that was writing needs, but how to reverse the progress?
Additional explaining, how to read wwxxyyzz from
file: FFDD0045wwxxyyzzFA23
python: wwxxyyzz (as value or string)
python: zzyyxxww (reversed)

If I could find as basic information, it would help me a lot to the new things to play with.
As you may see, this is my first post, so very newbie...

1.st EDIT: Okay, first I thank the fast answer, but as I am so new here, I could not comment, upvoted or so. That example is fitting for my file1, but file2-5 will be still hard to figure out, even with provided links, if there is not as clear and small (full) example. Also my question was rapidly marked as a duplicate, but on there was information still a bit not clear enough for a newbie like me. I have to continue with trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a basic example that will accomplish what you wanted for *writing* binary files

```
>>> filename = "file"
>>> file = open(filename,"wb")
>>> a = 254
>>> file.write(chr(a))
>>> file.close()
```

For reading binary files, and more examples:

1. [Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python)
2. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
3. [Binary file IO in python, where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967652/binary-file-io-in-python-where-to-start)